# lock a file and avoid the same process to access it twice

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I'm trying to use fcntl() file lock to mimic the semaphore among different processes.

I want to lock a dummy file in proc1 and use proc2 to unlock it;

proc1 will busy wait until proc2 unlock the file: proc1 will always check if the dummy file is locked; if it's locked, it will wait; otherwise, it will proceed.

However, it does NOT work! The problem is that:

If proc1 acquires the lock by using fcntl() function, when it check if the file is locked by using the fcntl() function's F_GETLK command, it will always think this file is unlocked.

My question is:
If I want to use the locking mechanism to achieve the semaphore behavior (as described above), what should I do? Is there any other better way to do it?

The lock and unlock function I used is as follows:

```
/*Lock the file and flag unconditionally unless fails in the fcntl()*/
static inline int lock_file(int fd)
{

    fd_lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fd_lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fd_lock.l_start = 0;
    fd_lock.l_len = 0;
    err = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fd_lock);
    if( err != 0)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Try to lock file %d which was locked by another proc; err=%d, errno=%d\n", fd, err, errno); 
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}

static inline int is_locked(int fd)
{


    fd_lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fd_lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fd_lock.l_start = 0;
    fd_lock.l_len = 0;
    err = fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fd_lock);
    //Could get the lock if not locked by another proc
    if(fd_lock.l_type == F_UNLCK) 
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: As I understood, according to the [doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) for F_GETLK: 

`If the lock could be placed,  fcntl() does not actually place it, but returns F_UNLCK`

Therefore, it only notifies that it's ok to lock this descriptor again for this process.

Answer (score 4):

Mutexes and semaphores are semantically different. `fcntl` locks (which are a type of mutex) have an owner, and only the owner can unlock them. Semaphores simply have a count and any thread/process can perform the increment or wait-decrement operation on them. I don't see any way to get semaphore semantics from `fcntl` locks.